# python 3 paramiko ssh agent forward over jump host with remote command on third host

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, paramiko, ssh-tunnel

Moin!

Situation: connect to the *destination.host* over the *jump.host* and run a command on the *destination.host*, which connects in the background to the *another.host* (on this host my ssh key is needed).

Scheme: client --> jump.host --> destination.host --- remote_command with ssh key needed on the other host --> another.host

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import paramiko

jumpHost=paramiko.SSHClient()
sshKey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('path.to.key/file', password = 'the.passphrase')
jumpHost.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
jumpHost.connect('jump.hostname',username='foo', pkey = sshKey)
jumpHostTransport = jumpHost.get_transport()
dest_addr = ('destination.hostname', 22) 
local_addr = ('jump.hostname', 22) 
jumpHostChannel = jumpHostTransport.open_channel("direct-tcpip", dest_addr, local_addr)

destHost=paramiko.SSHClient()
destHost.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
destHost.connect('destination.hostname', username='foo', sock=jumpHostChannel, pkey=sshKey)
destHostAgentSession = destHost.get_transport().open_session()
paramiko.agent.AgentRequestHandler(destHostAgentSession)

stdin, stderr, stdout = destHost.exec_command("my.command.which.connects.to.another.host")

print(stdout.read())
print(stderr.read())

destHost.close()
jumpHost.close()
```

The above code works well, if run "local" commands on the destination.host - e.g. uname, whoami, hostname, ls and so on... But if i run a command, which connects in the background to another host where my ssh key is needed, the code raised in the error:

**raise AuthenticationException("Unable to connect to SSH agent")
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Unable to connect to SSH agent**

If i connect via Putty at the same chain, it works well.

Can anyone give me a hint to resolve my problem?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Assumption:** Your keys work across jump host and destination host.

Creating a local agent in that case will work. You could manually create it via shell first and test it via iPython.

```
eval `ssh-agent`; ssh-add <my-key-file-path>
```

Programmatically this can be done -

```
# Using shell=True is not a great idea because it is a security risk.
# Refer this post - https://security.openstack.org/guidelines/dg_avoid-shell-true.html
subprocess.check_output("eval `ssh-agent`; ssh-add <my-key-file-path>", shell=True)
```

I am trying to do something similar and came across this post, I will update if I find a better solution.

EDIT: I have posted the implementation over here - https://adikrishnan.in/2018/10/25/agent-forwarding-with-paramiko/